# sorted() function affects the original list

Tags: python-3.x

I am testing some sorting algorithms by passing a list of strings to them. the structure is like this:

```
def test(test_case):
    ans = sorted(test_case)
    for f in functs:
        assert f(test_case) == ans
```

However, I found that `test_case` is changing all the time (I call `test()` for once). There is a time I passed `["Test", "String']` to `test()` and I put `print()` in my `f` to catch the input. I found that `f` received `[("Test", "String'), ("Test", "String'), ("Test", "String'), ("Test", "String'), ("Test", "String'), ...]`. May I know why this happened and what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` does not affect your original list (i.e., it does not sort the list in place), but if you execute the code on the interactive interpreter the output of `sorted` is going to be printed.
So what you see is the list sorted, followed by the original list.

```
['a', 'day', 'for', 'have', 'nice', 'reading', 'thanks']
['thanks', 'for', 'reading', 'have', 'a', 'nice', 'day']
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that the simplified one is misleading and have bo connection to my main problem.
I found the answer myself -- Functions will modify the list passed in.